# Comparator operator for objects to store it in a map

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, stdmap

I have the following class

```
class Person
{
  string name;
  string section;
};
```

What can be the implementation of the comparator operator to store this in a map ?

Comment: How do you want to order them?

Answer (score 3):

One possible implementation is this:

```
class Person
{
  string name;
  string section;
};

bool operator<(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}
```

This will sort lexicographically by name. Other orderings are possible, depending on what your needs are. Your question is a bit unclear, because usually you need two types for a map, a key-type and a value-type. The comparison is only required for the key-type, not for the value-type.

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

struct ComparePersons
{
  bool operator()(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) const
  {
    return std::tie(lhs.name, lhs,section) < std::tie(rhs.name, rhs.section);
  }
};
```

That performs a lexicographical less-than comparison, using `name` first and `section` second. Obviously this assumes you are interested in using `Person`s as keys of the map.